# Rails: Getting a Value from a Select Tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= form_tag 'select_domain', :url => administer_admin_domain_path(:id), :method => :get do %>
    <%= select_tag "id", options_from_collection_for_select(@domains, :id, :caption), :onchange => "this.form.submit();" %>
<% end %>
```

I want the option selected's id to be the :id inside my form's url when it submits, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
<%= form_tag 'select_domain', :url => administer_admin_domains_path, :method => :get do %>

 <%= select_tag "id", options_from_collection_for_select(@domains, :id, :caption), :onchange=>"this.form.action=this.form.action + '/' + this.value; this.form.submit(); %>

<% end %>
```

I didn't test the code. Just giving u some idea which might help. : )